# Understanding increment of variables in back tracking

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I am having trouble visualizing backtracking concept. I have gone through the code but I have trouble understanding one concept. The following is code to generate `permutations`

```
 private static  void helper(int start, int[] nums, List<List<Integer>> result){
        if(start==nums.length){
           //Add the nums array to result
            return;
        }


        for(int j=start; j<nums.length; j++){
         
            swap(nums, j, start);
            helper(start+1, nums, result);// here start variable is incremented in for  loop
            swap(nums, j, start);
        }
    }
```

Below is code for `subset` generation

```
private static void powerSet(int[] nums, int index, List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> li) {
        result.add(new ArrayList(li));

        if(index==nums.length){
            return;
        }

        for(int i=index;i<nums.length;i++){
            li.add(nums[i]);
            powerSet(nums,i+1,result,li); //here i is incremented in for loop
            li.remove(li.size()-1);
        }

    }
```

The above code works fine. I wanted to experiment a bit.  I tried changing the variable with `j+1` instead of `start+1` in recursion part for `permutations` code . This time I got wrong answer where permutations are duplicated . I tried to debug but I was unable to understand. Can someone please explain why we should use `start+1` and not `j+1` in case of `permutations` code. Similarly why we should use `i+1` and not `index+1` in case of `subset` code

Comment: Permutation looks goot to me.

Comment: My doubt is about incrementing the variables as mentioned in the post. Code works fine

Comment: Permutation doesn't even compile, i++ should be j++  .  Thinking about incrementing variables is misleading, each stackframe keeps separate values.

Comment: @NathanHughes I edited the question . I think I am having hard time even to express my idea

Comment: The words you use suggest to me that, while it's not your main problem, you don't understand argument passing or variable scope. "// here start variable is incremented in for  loop".  No, it isn't. The value of 'start+1' is assigned as the initial value of the formal argument of the inner activation of 'helper' -- which is a **different variable** named 'start'.  Nothing done to the inner 'start' affects the outer 'start'.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain.

Permutations recursive tree of input (1,2,3) when using swaps will look as follows:

```
          _____________(1,2,3)_____________   start = 0, swap idx 0 with each idx >= 0
         /                |                \
        /                 |                 \
    (1,2,3)            (2,1,3)            (3,2,1)  start = 1, swap idx 1 with each idx >= 1
     /    \             /    \            /     \
    /      \           /      \          /       \
(1,2,3)  (1,3,2)   (2,1,3)  (2,3,1)   (3,2,1)  (3,1,2)  ...
```

I believe you should see the pattern now: `start` iterates `[0..3)`, and `j` iterates `[start..n)`. That's why you pass `start + 1` into the next recursive call, to ensure exactly such processing order.

Subsets algorithm is different. Once the i-th element is included into a subset `li.add(nums[i])`, the algorithm should make sort of a "cut", meaning the next recursive call should iterate through the remaining part of the array only, hence you have `i + 1`.

Hope it helps at least a little bit.

Comment: Thanks!! It makes sense now. I guess I was downvoted for my poor choice of words to explain my problem.